# How to use graphql api with react frontEnd?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, graphcool

I have graphcool api endpoint, now I want to implement frontEnd for it
If you know how to get started with reactjs-graphcool give references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to get started with Apollo Client is by using Apollo Boost, our starter kit that configures your client for you with our recommended settings.

you can get more detail on this link...

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html